# In java is ternary operator considered a single line expression while using inside a lambda function?

Tags: java, lambda, ternary

```
Collections.sort(employees, (employee1, employee2) -> {
    return (employee1.getAge() >= employee2.getAge()) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

The above code sample sorts the 'employees' List according to age just fine. But, the code below gives an error.

```
Collections.sort(employees, (employee1, employee2) ->
    employee1.getAge() >= employee2.getAge() ? -1 : 1;
);
```

Isn't the ternary operator considered as a single line expression?
The error shown is:

> java: ')' expected;
> java: illegal start of expression

Comment: Your comparison expression is not correct. It gives the wrong output if the elements are equal.

Comment: And there is no such thing in Java as a 'single line expression', and nothing about it in the error message.

Comment: @user207421 I think because of '>=' it won't give the wrong output if the elements are equal. And actually, I didn't know the exact words to frame it so I used 'single line expression' 

Comment: You are mistaken. It is required to return zero if the elements are equal.

Answer (score 4):

Syntactically, the [lambda body](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2) (the thing after `->`) is either a *block* or an expression.

If it's a *block*, then it must contain zero or more *statements*. The `return` statement ends with a `;`, which is why `;` is needed in the first case.

In the second case, you attempted to write a [conditional expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) ("ternary operator"), but as you can see in the syntax, the trailing `;` is not part of a conditional expression, (AFAIK, no expression ends with a `;`) so you've written something extra that the parser didn't expect, which causes the code to not compile.

So you should delete the `;`:

```
Collections.sort(employees, (employee1, employee2) ->
    employee1.getAge() >= employee2.getAge() ? -1 : 1
);
```

Also, note that this implementation of `Comparator` does not ensure that `sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))` for all `x` and `y`, which is part of the contract of `Comparator.compare`. `sort` will not work correctly.